# Typehinting traversable objects

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, type-hinting

Let's say you are building an API that other people will work with.
And you use typehinting a lot for functions, like `function foo(array $arg){...}`. This forces the argument to be an array, so passing traversable objects to this function won't work. But your function can work with such objects.

Do you think it's a good idea to remove the hint and handle traversable objects too? Or should I leave that to the user? (she can use `iterator_to_array` for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might remove the type hint I suppose and put a PHPDoc comment. on saying it takes an array, a traversable or even arrayaccess.

It's not bad the user to give flexibility when they use your API, however your API should work fault tolerant when handling arguments that are not of the appropriate type. So if you remove the type hinting, you should add type controls to your methods (of course you don't have to but it might be considered as a best practice). However making checks causes your API to slow down (it might be negligent and might be considered a micro optimisation however if your API needs to work fast you should also consider this).